PostgreSql Publication/subscription issue
I have 2 different databases suppose one is in ...1 and another in ...2
I want that if any operation like insert/update/delete occurs in db-1 then that should get affected in db-2
I followed all the steps mentioned below

on server-1 set wal_level = logical in postgresql.conf file
on server-1 added host  db-name     user-name           ..*.2/32      md5
on server-1 added host all all ..*.1/32 md5
created role with all permission in db-1 ..*.1
in server-1 created publication using below query
CREATE PUBLICATION my_publication FOR ALL TABLES;
in server-2 created subscription using below query
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription
CONNECTION 'host=..*.1port=5432 dbname=your_primary_db user=replication_user password=your_password'
PUBLICATION my_publication;
After making config file changes restarted the posgres service as well

But the issue still remains
if i make any change in server-1 than that is not reflected in server-2
I am not able to figure out why the data is not reflected.Can anyone help me out on why this is happening or how can this be figured out
I simply want that data from server-1 should be synced to server-2 if nay operation happens.
i am using pgadmin tool and posgres version is 16

I'd say you didn't create the tables on the subscriber. Check the log file on the subscriber!

I don't want logs instead replicate the data in the table directly

I mean, look at the logs for the error messages.
